# donate command sends the same pic for all streamers even though i wanted the bot to send it for one person | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I made a donate command. However, I want to make it much better.

**I was thinking of this:**

- The bot should only respond with the image when Carson is the one being donated. Currently, It donates to all streamers
- Bot should only take money, and not words.

````py
  @commands.command()
  async def donate(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Aight, Who do you want to donate to?")
    streamer = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message : message.author == ctx.author)
    await ctx.send(f"Ok, so you are donating to {streamer.content}. How much money you gonna donate?")
    amount = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message : message.author == ctx.author)
    await ctx.send(f"Aight, you are donating ${amount.content} to {streamer.content}. What's the donatation message?")
    donation = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message : message.author == ctx.author)
    await ctx.send(f"You have just donated ${amount.content} to {streamer.content} with the message: {donation.content}")
    if streamer.content == "CallMeCarson" or "callmecarson" or "carson":
      await ctx.send(file=discord.File("./Images/callmecarsoncrying.jpg"))
      return```
Im new to python, So sorry if this is very easy to do.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the following line:

```
if streamer.content == "CallMeCarson" or "callmecarson" or "carson":
```

This means the same as the folllowing:

```
if streamer.content == "CallMeCarson" or string == True or string == True:
```

Non-empty strings in python are `truthy`, so this will always be `True` & pass, so it will always work for every streamer.

When using `and` or `or` in python, you need to repeat the argument you're trying to compare.

```
if streamer.content == "CallMeCarson" or streamer.content == "callmecarson" or streamer.content == "carson":
```

But this is obsolete, as you can just cast it to lowercase & check if `carson` is in there:

```
if "carson" in streamer.content.lower():
```

Assuming you plan on doing this for multiple streamers, I recommend making a `dict` to avoid 900 if-statements. You can just add all of the other names & image paths to this dict in the future.

```
streamers = {"carson": "callmecarsoncrying", "streamer2": "streamer2_image_name"}
for key in streamers:
    if key in streamer.content.lower():
        return await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"./Images/{streamers[key]}.jpg"))
```

The last line will send the message & then `break` out of the loop (by `returning`) when it finds a match, so none of the other streamers will be checked. This way, the code looks a lot cleaner & easier to maintain.